# My little Python program to print from a list doesn't work in real life like it does on my Treehouse course.

Tags: python, list, printing, return

I have a file called test.py, which has this code inside:

```
import random

def random_item(nasgul):
    pick = random.randint(0, len(nasgul)-1)
    print(nasgul[pick])
```

and I have also tried to replace the last line with

```
return nasgul[pick]
```

but in my terminal, when I called it by writing

```
python3 test.py
```

nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

If that is all of that code that is in the file, then nothing is going to happen.  All that you did in this file was define a function, you are not calling it.  You need a list to pass into the function, see the following

```
import random

nasgul = ['sword','dagger', 'axe']

def random_item(nasgul):
    pick = random.randint(0, len(nasgul)-1)
    print(nasgul[pick])

random_item(nasgul)
```